# CSS is loading only for the main page but not for the next pages

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-mvc-test

I have used spring boot with Thymeleaf (thymeleaf starter dependency is added).

The css files are places under `src/main/resources/static` and the 
html files are placed under `src/main/resources/templates`

The spring main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`(As usual).

Say in First controller for `/ui` ,  I am returning index.html. It loads the CSS.

Say in a method for Url "ui/video/viewAll", I am returning `abc.html` (with content- fragment concept - using the same layout of index.html. Seems css files are loaded for this html alone.

Not sure why this behaviour?
Can anybody explain why is this happening?

Comment: Could you post (relevant parts of) index.html and abc.html? Hard to figure out what's wrong with the code if we don't see the code  I'm guessing the css files aren't loaded through the layout fragment, and thus not included in abc.html

Comment: It's probably because you're using relative urls for your css.

Comment: @Metroids should probably be right about this one. You should be using using relative urls for CSS and if your layout fragment usage is correct than relative urls must be the case